# How to simplify the use of angular material dialog?

Tags: angular, angular-material

There is a less bureaucratic way of working with angular 2 material dialog? Or another alternative of dialog?

Angular 2 material dialog needs a component to work. The communication process between the component that uses the dialog and the dialog is extensive. I just want the content that is hidden inside the page to be shown inside a dialog. There could be a showDialog property to control the display of the dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so it is possible to do so. Here is a simple example that I used and it is pretty simple:

Simple component: https://github.com/reflexdemon/shop/blob/master/src/app/lost/lost.component.ts#L45-L59

Code to open the dialog: https://github.com/reflexdemon/shop/blob/master/src/app/lost/lost.component.ts#L31-L37

Further reading: https://material.angular.io/components/component/dialog